# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'quantity' django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to do a cart system where an user can add a product to the cart and if it was already in there I would add one of it but I keep getting the error "'tuple' object has no attribute 'quantity' django".

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    cart = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    order = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Orders(models.Model) :
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)


def add_to_cart(request, pk) :
    item = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    order_item = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
        item = item,
        user = request.user,
        order = False
    )
    order_qs = Orders.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]

        if order.items.filter(item__pk=item.pk).exists() :
            order_item.quantity += 1
            order_item.save()
            return redirect("product-detail", pk = pk)
        else:
            order.items.add(order_item)
            return redirect("product-detail", pk = pk)
    else:
        order = Orders.objects.create(user=request.user)
        order.items.add(order_item)
        return redirect("product-detail", pk = pk)
```

Comment: get_or_create as per docstring: "[...] Returns a tuple of (object, created) [...]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_or_create()` returns a tuple containing the object and a boolean indicating whether the object was created or not.

To fix the issue you need to change the code to this:

```
order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
    item=item,
    user=request.user,
    order=False
)
```